# why can I pass multiple pointers to a single pointer param?

Tags: c, pointers

I just found that I can pass a double pointer to a function requiring a single pointer as param.

```cpp
void func(void *p) {}

void **p;
func(p);
```

And I can even do this:

```cpp
void memcpy(void *dst, void *src) {}

void ****dst, *********src;
memcpy(dst, src);
```

It seems an implicit conversion happened.

But, what is the rule of this kind of conversion? and what does standard say?

Comment: It is not a double pointer, rather a pointer to pointer.

Comment: A pointer to a pointer (i.e. **p) is also a pointer, so nothing wrong here.

Comment: better choose either C or C++, also you tagged *language-desgin*, but the question is rather about the status quo. A question about language design would be eg "Why does a language allow such conversion?"

Comment: And what is the problem? Maybe you want total control from compiler - to catch anything which seems strange. Choose another language for this.

Comment: The key here is that `void*` and only that type is the generic pointer type in C. It can be converted to/from any other pointer type implicitly. This includes `void**` which is a pointer type but _not_ the generic pointer type, only `void*` is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a function is called, then (6.5.2.2):

> ...the arguments are implicitly converted, as if by assignment, to the types of the
> corresponding parameters

So in order to see if we are allowed to do pass something to a function, we need to check the rules for assignment. Among the rules for simple assignment, all valid forms are listed, including this one (6.5.16.1, emphasis mine):

> - the left operand has atomic, qualified, or unqualified pointer type, and (considering the type the left operand would have after lvalue conversion) **one operand is a pointer to an object type, and the other is a pointer to a qualified or unqualified version of `void`**, and the type pointed to by the left has all the qualifiers of the type pointed to by the right;

This means that we are allowed to implicitly assign an object pointer type to a `void*` and the other way around. Same thing when we pass parameters to a function.

This is why you get no diagnostic messages, `void*` is a special case, it is a generic object pointer type that can be used together with any other object pointer type. Note that I use the term *object pointer*, because you can't mix `void*` with function pointers.

How the actual conversion is carried out is specified in 6.3.2.3:

> A pointer to `void` may be converted to or from a pointer to any object type. A pointer to any object type may be converted to a pointer to `void` and back again; the result shall compare equal to the original pointer.

These special rules only apply to `void*`. They do not apply "recursively" to `void**`. But a `void**` is still an object pointer type, so you can assign it to a `void*` etc for that reason. But you cannot go from for example `double**` to `void**`.

Note however that qualifiers (`const`, `volatile`) must be respected as written in 6.5.16.1 above. We can assign from a non-qualified type to a qualified type, but not the other way around. (Also see 6.3.2.3/2)

Answer (score 1):

It’s specifically (optionally const/volatile) `void *`.
Any pointer can be converted to it as long as it won’t lose the topmost const/volatile.

Answer (score 1):

> what is the rule of this kind of conversion? and what does standard say?

[C11 6.3.2.3p1](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.3p1):

> A pointer to void may be converted to or from a pointer to any object type. A pointer to any object type may be converted to a pointer to void and back again; the result shall compare equal to the original pointer.

Comment: This is actually not the reason why implicit conversion is allowed.

Answer (score 0):

`void* ptr`, is a pointer with an address.

`void** ptr`, is also a pointer with an address.

Thereby you are just passing an address which can be stored in any pointer.